# retrive a result from a website by an ajax post request

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, web-scraping, http-headers

I'm tryng to perfom a simple ajax post request to retrieve some data from a website.
In detail i'm trying to contact a page that a website recall to have some informations.
So i have the main website and a page that it calls to retrive data.
I discovered that page using the google inspection section, in particular in the **xhr** section of **network** field of the inspector.
In my code i used all the headers and the payload data that are used by the website to contact the page.
This is the code that i'm using to reach my goal:

```
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
    var url = 'https://www.remax.pt/Webservices/MainWebService.asmx/GetCityList';
var body = {"SiteRegionID":"12","RegionID":"12","RegionRowID":"78","ProvinceID":"0",
"LanguageCode":"ITA","MinInternetCount":"0","SearchType":"","OfficeAgent":"0",
"EncodingLanguage":"PTG","OfficeAgentId":"0"};

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function () {
    var data = xhr.responseText;
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
        console.table("results: "+data);
    } else {
        console.error("error: "+data);
    }
}
    xhr.open("POST", url, true); 
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/html");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("authority", "www.remax.pt");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("scheme", "https");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("path", "/Webservices/MainWebService.asmx/GetCityList");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("accept-language","it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7");
    //xhr.setRequestHeader('accept-encoding', 'gzip, deflate, br');
    //xhr.setRequestHeader("host", "https://www.remax.pt");
    //xhr.setRequestHeader('referer', 'https://www.remax.pt/PublicListingList.aspx');
    //xhr.setRequestHeader('content-length', '192');    
    //xhr.setRequestHeader('cookie','__cfduid=dc7dd48ccff40ee4f85840bfc35685b311531384150; PersonalizationMap=; PersonalizationGallery=SelectedCountryID=12; GtTransLang=ITA; SLINGSHOT=LanguageCode=it-IT; SessionId=1ac0ec84-6a03-4965-ba90-7eb686f66bf5; ASP.NET_SessionId=rgia1pblms2abf11ypsbiqgz; GtTrans=ENU; LastSearch=SiteRegionID=12&TransactionTypeUID=260&RegionID=12&RegionRowID=78&LocationText=Porto&LocationValue=YR78&PriceCurrency=EUR&ComRes=2; PersonalizationRegion=#mode=list&tt=260&cr=2&r=78&cur=EUR&la=All&sb=PriceIncreasing&page=1&sc=12&sid=a81a1d1d-ee36-4236-a72e-31343349c574; PersonalizationDate=2018-7-24 10:0:30');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(body);
```

Actually i never receive an answer. I think that the flow of operations never enter in the onLoad section because the string that there are in if and else sections are never printed.
I wanna specify that some headers are commented because i had an answer of this type:
*Refused to set unsafe header 'nameHeader'*
So i decided to do not use them for the moment.

I tried to change some headers or add something new but the problem remains and honestly i don't have idea if it is a problem of syntax of some fields or if i need other things to perform an acceptable request.

for completeness i insert the 4 fields that i found in the inspector tool that specify the parameters passed by the website to call the page:

**GENERAL**:

```
 1. Request URL:       
    https://www.remax.pt/Webservices/MainWebService.asmx/GetCityList
 2. Request Method: POST 
 3. Status Code: 200  
 4. Remote Address: 104.25.40.105:443
 5. Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**RESPONSE HEADERS**:

1. List item
2. cache-control: private, max-age=0
3. cf-ray: 43f532b9e9886260-LIS
4. content-encoding: br
5. content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
6. date: Tue, 24 Jul 2018 09:00:44 GMT
7. expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
8. server: cloudflare
9. status: 200
10. x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
11. x-ua-compatible: IE=9, IE=8

**REQUEST HEADERS**:

1. authority: www.remax.pt
2. method: POST
3. path: /Webservices/MainWebService.asmx/GetCityList
4. scheme: https
5. accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
6. accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
7. accept-language: it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
8. content-length: 192
9. content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
10. cookie: __cfduid=dc7dd48ccff40ee4f85840bfc35685b311531384150; PersonalizationMap=; PersonalizationGallery=SelectedCountryID=12; GtTransLang=ITA; SLINGSHOT=LanguageCode=it-IT; SessionId=1ac0ec84-6a03-4965-ba90-7eb686f66bf5; ASP.NET_SessionId=rgia1pblms2abf11ypsbiqgz; GtTrans=ENU; LastSearch=SiteRegionID=12&TransactionTypeUID=260&RegionID=12&RegionRowID=78&LocationText=Porto&LocationValue=YR78&PriceCurrency=EUR&ComRes=2; PersonalizationRegion=#mode=list&tt=260&cr=2&r=78&cur=EUR&la=All&sb=PriceIncreasing&page=1&sc=12&sid=a81a1d1d-ee36-4236-a72e-31343349c574; PersonalizationDate=2018-7-24 10:0:30
11. origin: https://www.remax.pt
12. referer: https://www.remax.pt/PublicListingList.aspx
13. user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
14. x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest

**REQUEST PAYLOAD**:
{"SiteRegionID":"12","RegionID":"12","RegionRowID":"78","ProvinceID":"0","LanguageCode":"ITA","MinInternetCount":"0","SearchType":"","OfficeAgent":0,"EncodingLanguage":"PTG","OfficeAgentId":0}

Comment: ok now i find an answer in this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284680/how-to-send-data-to-asmx-web-service-via-ajax-post. The problem now is that i receive the html of the internal server error 500. the messagge says: "There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed".

Comment: ok i solved the problem. For those that wanna know it, i need to add the following header to the request: 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-type'